# How to view remotely mapped drive in the Windows command line

Tags: windows-7, sftp, cmd.exe

I'm using Expandrive 3 to map a remote drive to the `Z:\` drive on my computer. I would like to view it using the command line from Windows 7, but trying `cd Z:\` doesn't do anything. No error message, nothing.

Does anyone know if there's a way to view a drive other than `C:\` using the command line in Windows?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What is a mapped drive to a remote drive? Do you mean a mapped drive to a remote Share? Have you tried simply running `CD Z:`? How about running `net use`? Do you see the Z: drive?

Comment: I can see the remote drive. running CD Z: outputs the text "Z:\" and that's it.

Comment: have you typed 'dir'?

Comment: well, like i said, the CD command didn't do anything. If I run 'dir' after trying to CD it still returns the contents of my home folder.

Comment: type z: without the backslash and hit enter

Comment: Type `Z:` at the command prompt and hit enter. You should then be in the Z: drive. Type `dir` to confirm that the directory contents are those of the Z: drive.

Comment: Just type `Z:`, no `cd` and no slash. The `cd` command is for changing directories not drives.

Comment: Its worth noting that powershell does CD to other drives in one operation. I don't tend to use cmd.exe much anymore, since PS is just generally better and it recognizes standard bash FS commands like ls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not specific to network shared drives. This is the normal behavior of `cd` command under windows. You should read the contents of the help notes provided with `cd` command. A quote from `cd` help notes:

> Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing
>   current directory for a drive.

The syntax you want is

```
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
```

This will allow you to `cd` to a different drive. If /D switch is not used, you can only change the directory within your current drive.

Another alternative is to explicitly change the drive before issuing `cd` command. in your case this would look like this

> [drive:]
>
> CD [path]

First line will change the drive to whatever drive you want, use Z: in your case (note no backslash after column), second line will change directory to [path]

Answer (score 2):

When cd'ing to a drive, older versions of cmd.exe do not go straight there. 
after issuing your CD command, type the drive letter : but without a backslash.
The reason is because CD is only for changing directories, not drives, and they technically have differant syntax. you don't actually need to CD at all to just switch drives

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\user>cd d:\

    C:\Users\user>d:

    d:\>c:

    C:\Users\user>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command (without `/D` switch) cannot change current working directory to another drive. For that use `X:` command (where `X` is a drive to change to).

The `cd X:\path` does not do nothing though. It changes current directory on `X:` drive to `path`. So if you do `cd X:\path` followed by `X:` you end up in `X:\path`. Every drive in Windows remembers its working directory. The `X:` command does not change to a root directory of the drive, but to a working directory on the drive (root being default).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the /D swtich for CD will change the drive and then change the current working directory.

This works with both drive letters assigned to local drives and also to network drive letters mapped to network UNC shares or remote storage servers via programs like ExpanDrive or WebDrive.

More information on the MSDOS CD command can be found at http://www.computerhope.com/cdhlp.htm

Comment: Would be helpful to have the relevant information from the external link.